# Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy error Rendering reddit image. With crossorigin attribute set to null

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, d3.js, cross-domain

I pretty sure this is a easy fix, but I can't put a finger on the error. I'm loading a local JSON file into d3, my application works just fine other than the fact that it won't render my images in my JSON. This only happens when I'm using Chrome. I have set headers server side, I'm currently trying to set the headers on the Image attribute. I think that is where the problem is. **Look at the Second Image**. If you take a look at the second image you will  notice that crossorigin is set to nothing, right? I think thats part of the issue. Let me know if I need to put up any more info. I really want fix this error it's driving me crazy.

I have gone ahead and tried to set the images origin headers, but I'm still having no luck running my application on chrome. [setting img cross origin docs](http://blog.chromium.org/2011/07/using-cross-domain-images-in-webgl-and.html)

**Photo of error in chrome debugger tool**
[image: Photo of error in chrome debugger tool] 
**Crossorigin is set to nothing!?**

[image: Crossorigin is set to nothing!?]

**Photo of code block that I think might be the colporate**
[image: Snippet of code block]

Comment: Are you using http requests to get data and are you running the file directly in browser.

Comment: I'm loading the data from a local JSON file.

Comment: Can you share a fiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pnon4kzw/

Comment: Can you add complete code as I am sure it has do with `url` and also let me know are you running it on chrome directly.

Comment: Here is a fiddle to the logic written for my application https://jsfiddle.net/qso5ynz2/

Comment: Try running your code in a webserver.

Comment: Already running it on a web server

Comment: Interesting can you replicate this issue in fiddle.